# Expected '> ' to equal '> ' in jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm testing jQuery terminal and I got error:

```
Expected '> ' to equal '> '.
```

when testing:

```
$(function() {
    describe('Terminal plugin', function() {
        describe('terminal create terminal destroy', function() {
            var term = $('<div id="term"></div>').appendTo('body').terminal();
            it('should have default prompt', function() {
                var prompt = term.find('.prompt');
                expect(prompt.html()).toEqual("<span>&gt;&nbsp;</span>");
                expect(prompt.text()).toEqual('> ');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

they are same value I just copy it into console and replace `to equal` by `==` or `===` and it return `true`.

Comment: can you provide a complete example to reproduce?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`&nbsp;` is not a "regular" space, so `"&gt;&nbsp;"` and `"> "` are not equivalent.

Instead, try `expect(prompt.text()).toEqual('>\xA0')`, that being the hex code for a non-breaking space (it's a better idea than putting an actual non-breaking space in there!)