# How to verify a dynamic value with a space using jasmine expect(check).toContain(value)?

Tags: user-interface, selenium-webdriver, protractor, ui-automation

I want to validate a value , which is dynamic and retrieved from one page to another. That element also has space on it.
Below is my coding for that.

Page - 1

```
var PerAge = element(by.css("h1 > span.ng-binding")).getText();
```

This element has space on it , like this - >`&nbsp;name`

Page-2 - > same value displayed in an other page. This element has no space on it.

```
var HumAge = element(by.repeater("slide in ctrl.slides track by $index")).getText();
```

Now, I want to validate the value on Page 2 is same or not. Since , the repeater has bunch of other values , so I am using .toContain to validate the value.
The issue here is , the PerAge has space on it.

I checked this stack overflow question , but it did not work.
[Expected '> ' to equal '> ' in jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464562/expected-to-equal-in-jasmine).

```
expect(PerAge).toContain(HumAge);
```

Its returning following error

> Expected 'Shane' to contain ' Shane'.

I tried `trim`, It doesn't recognize trim.
I cannot use `.ToEqual` like below since the element have bunch of other things.

```
expect(PerAge).toEqual('\xA0HumAge')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you retrieve a value on page 1 like this:

```
var PerAge = element(by.css("h1 > span.ng-binding")).getText();
```

and use it on page 2 to compare it:

```
var HumAge = element(by.repeater("slide in ctrl.slides track by $index")).getText()
expect(HumAge).toEqual(PerAge);
```

This fails due to the spaces.

The reason why you can't use `.trim()` is because `.getText()` returns a promise. You first need to resolve the promise before you can use `.trim()`.

What you can do is for example this. You also find an example of the code if you use a transpiler like Babel or use TypeScript which both support Async/Await.

```js
var PerAge, HumAge;

element(by.css("h1 > span.ng-binding")).getText()
  .then(function(text) {
    PerAge = text.trim();
  });

// Go to page 2
element(by.repeater("slide in ctrl.slides track by $index")).getText()
  .then(function(text) {
    HumAge = text.trim();
  });

expect(HumAge).toEqual(PerAge);


// If you can use async await because you transpile with Babel or use typescript you can do this to tidy the code
// $ is the Protractor shorthand for the `css`-locator
const PerAge = (await $('h1 > span.ng-binding').getText()).trim();
const HumAge = (await $('[ng-repeater="slide in ctrl.slides track by $index"]').getText()).trim();

expect(HumAge).toEqual(PerAge);
```